# How can I define a Jira custom field whose value is shared among, and automatically updated to, all the issues that use it, like a static variable?

Tags: jira, custom-field-type

I am looking to use a custom field assigned to a sub task screen. If that custom field is updated in one issue, it should update and reflect the changes in all the issues that use the same field. To make an example, it should work like a static member of a class that has the same value for all the objects of that class.

Please suggest how I can do this.

Comment: "If same field is updated in one issue it should be updated and reflect in all issues that used same field?" I don't understand, is this really a question? In general, when a field in an issue is updated, no other issue is affected. But I suspect the question mark at the end of that sentence is wrong, and you are not asking about this behaviour, you are rather  describing the behaviour you would like to have. Am I right?

Comment: yes. I need behavior like static data if in one issue  updated all other issues that used should be updated and shows latest value.